# Usar error handler o extender objecto response en express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Buenas,
estoy realizando un proyecto REST API utilizando Express y con la intención de refactorizar el código para retornar al cliente una respuesta de error no sé cual de las siguientes opciones es más eficiente:

Utilizar un [manejador de errores](http://expressjs.com/es/guide/error-handling.html) como especifica la guía de Express.

```
app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
  console.log('ERROR HANDLER: ', err);
  res.status(err.status || 500).send(err); //custom error
});
```

de forma que en cada `catch` de una Promesa...

```
function(req, res, next) {
 Promise
 .then( ... ) // throw error
 .catch(next)
}
```

---

O [extender el objeto response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18307732/6659123) de la siguiente forma:

```
express.response.error_ = function(err){
  this.status(err.status || 500).send(err);
}
```

de esta forma podré ejecutar...

```
function(req, res, next) {
 Promise
 .then( ... ) // throw error
 .catch(res.error_)
}
```

¿Cúal de éstas es la mejor opción?

Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pienso que seria mejor usar la primera forma, como indica la guia de Express, ya que es mas facil poder hacer un testing directamente de este handler sin depender de express tan solo mockeando los objetos req y res ademas de tener arquitectura mas "limpia", por ejemplo puedes tener tu handler de esta manera en un archivo customErrorHandler.js:

```
//middlewares/customErrorHanlder.js
module.exports = function customErrorHandler(err,req,res){
    //Procesamiento del error
}

//app.js
var customErrorHandler = require("./middlewares/customErrorHandler")
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function(req, res,next){
 //Procesamiento get
 next(new Error("error"))
});


app.use(customErrorHandler);

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor manera es crear un manejador de errores al final de todo el documento, es decir detrás de todas las rutas. En dichas rutas debes pasar nu nuevo error por next() y ese error será recogido por en manejador de errores.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    // Creamos el error y lo pasamos al manejador 
    // Acuérdate de utilizar 'var' ya que necesitamos un scope global 
    var err = new Error("Mensaje de error");
    next(err);
});

/*
 * Otras rutas GET, POST, etc...
 */

//El error es 
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500);
    res.send("Oops, something went wrong.")
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: ¿Por qué es mejor esta opción?